# selenium with python making a list to excel

Tags: python, list, selenium, loops

I'm trying to export the data in the list to an excel file. I tried many ways to loop through the variables, the problem is that some times the script fails to locate some data and I get StaleElementReferenceException

I need that the loop will ignore variables if there is no data inside

```
 with open('items.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([driver.current_url])
        items_list = [item_1.text, number_1, item_2.text, number_2, item_3.text, number_3, item_4.text, number_4,
                         item_5.text, number_5, item_6.text, number_6, item_7.text, number_7, item_8.text, number_8,
                         item_9.text, number_9, item_10.text, number_10]
        items_data= writer.writerow(items_list)
        all_items_list = all(items_list)
        for i in range(all_items_list):
            if i == 0:
                pass
            else:
                items_data
```

tried those also

```
 for i in range(all_items_list):
            if items_data[0::2] > 0:
                items_data
            elif items_data[0::2] == 0:
                pass

  for i in range(all_items_list):
            if i > 0:
                items_data
            else:
                pass
```

this code works the best but I do get errors sine times:

```
 for i in range(all_items_list):
            if i != "":
                pass
            else:
                items_data
```

Comment: what errors you get ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the `range` function correctly. It expects a integer a produces a list of numbers.

If you want to loop through a collection, just use something like `for x in mylist:`

Try this code:

```
 for i in all_items_list:
     if i:     # if i not 0\None\"" 
        items_data  # do something here with i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([driver.current_url])
        writer.writerow([item_1.text, number_1, item_2.text, number_2, item_3.text, number_3, item_4.text, number_4,item_5.text, number_5])
     driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

actually implementing implicitly_wait and deleting the looping part solved all the errors